# How to select particular text checkbox when we have multiple checkbox using sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I have 5 Horizontal check boxes in Adobe Live Cycle forms. I have imported Sikuli jars to support for selenium code. I have written a portion of Sikuli code and calling from Selenium Test case.

The problem which i am facing is:

Eg.,

```
 _        _        _
|_| Card |_| Cash |_| Check
```

I wanted to check first time Card, and the subsequent times, i have to change Cash, Check, DD etc.

If I capture Checkbox alone in sikuli, always it selects First Checkbox which is card.

If I capture image with Text, it clicks on the on the center, so it is just clicking the text and not checkbox..

Is there anyway I can do this.. I have seen few examples to use Target offset (http://doc.sikuli.org/tutorials/checkone/checkone.html) but since I am using Sikuli jar, it is not possible I guess.

Can someone faced the similar kind of problem and have any solution for this?

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

You could try to find all the coincidences of checkbox in the screen, using **findAll()**. Then, save the coordinates into lists and after that, order and click them. Let me show you an example:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import org.sikuli.script.Finder;
import org.sikuli.script.Match;
import org.sikuli.script.Region;
import org.sikuli.script.*;
import org.sikuli.script.ImageLocator;

public class Test {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException, FindFailed {
            // Define 2 list to get X and Y
            List <Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
            List <Integer> y = new ArrayList<>();
            Test t = new Test();
            t.getCoordinates(x,y);
            t.clickOnTarget(x,y);
        }

        public void clickOnTarget(List <Integer> x, List <Integer> y) throws AWTException {
            Robot r = new Robot();

            for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) { // From 0 to the number of checkboxes saved on X list
                r.mouseMove(x.get(i), y.get(i));
                r.delay(500);
                r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); //Press click
                r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); // Release click
                r.delay(5000);
                // And your code goes here
            }
        }

        public void getCoordinates(List <Integer> x, List <Integer> y) throws FindFailed {
            ImagePath.add("D:\\workplace\\test\\img\\");
            Screen s = new Screen();
            Iterator <Match> matches = s.findAll(new Pattern("CheckBoxImg.png").similar(0.9f)); // Get all coincidences and save them
            Match archivo;
            Location l;
            while (matches.hasNext()) { 
                Match m = matches.next(); // Get next value from loop
                l = new Location(m.getTarget()); // Get location
                // Add to the list of coordinates
                x.add(l.getX());
                y.add(l.getY());
                System.out.println("Coordinates: x: "  + l.getX() + " y: " + l.getY());
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see, you don't need to return both Lists. Only set them in the function getCoordinates and it will fill them.

The documentation for JavaDoc API can be found [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/index.html)

I hope it will help you. I invest an hour of my life :-)

Comment: Thanks for ur help.

Comment: You're welcome! And let me tell you; TargetOffset is available at Sikuli java api. You can find it following the link that I provided at the end of my answer =)